# What is the actual meaning and purpose of saying "I'm in a call"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

What is the actual meaning and purpose of saying "I'm in a call"

Ex: if a person pinged me when am talking with someone over phone at the same time then what would be the simple and correct way to say that "am talking with someone over phone.."

Comment: I'd have thought 'on a call' rather than 'in a call' was more usual.

Comment: Perhaps: "On a call" in England, "in a call" in the US?

Comment: @BarrieEngland I agree; being “in” a call just doesn’t sound right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatically in British English:

> I'm on the phone.

Other possibilites:

> I'm in the middle of a call
>
> I'm on another line

Comment: It’s the same in North America.

Answer (score 4):

In a US office environment, "I'm in a call" would be short for "I'm in a conference call." A conference call is set up as a location or meeting place, hence people say they are "in a call," rather than "on a call."

Answer (score 0):

`I am on a call` would be a better option